# Migrate 2008 SSIS package to 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

We upgraded our SQL Server from 2008 R2 to 2019, about time I know. I have hundreds of packages that need to be migrated. I have tried Migrating them directly through Solution exp "Add existing", Using the SSDT Package Migration wizard, and Migrating them to VS 2015 then to 2019. They all give the same results. All the Script tasks\Components have errors. when you open the script there are not errors. When you close the script it says "The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully." The only other clue is a warning inside the Script editor. I think I understand what its saying but don't know how to change the target arch with out deleting the script and recreating it. This is a pain because I have a hundred packages and most have more than one Script. Please help. Thank you.

> Warning: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
> Blockquote

BTW when I migrate to BI 2015 or 2017 there is no problem. Just seems to be be a 2019 issue.

Comment: `All the Script tasks\Components have errors`. What are the errors that you are getting? Are you using any custom components?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the build warning, ignore it. I get them too. What's going on here is that it is checking the CPU platform. For debugging purposes, we have to run in x86 because Visual Studio is 32-bit (i.e., x86) and this is a known issue for debugging SSIS packages. When you deploy to a SQL Server, it is more than likely that it will be running a 64-bit chip (i.e., x64)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I Don't like errors but  the real issue is why do all the scripting tasks have to be rewritten. Like I said it didn't happen going in 2015, I have a coworker converting to 2017 and they have not had this issue it seems to just be 2019. Anyway I am rewriting all the script tasks. I just copy the code from the 2008 script and paste it in the 2019 version.